# Is there purely recursive functions?

Tags: recursion

Is there any problem that can be only solved with recursion, and not with iteration? (haven't been able to find anything online).

If there isn't any, is there a reason why?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Böhm–Jacopini theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_program_theorem) states that everything can be implemented using just IFs and WHILEs. Indeed, your CPU essentially implements an infinite WHILE loop with conditional execution.

Recursion can be simulated iteratively using a stack; this is how recursion is implemented under the hood. Conversely, the same construction as in the theorem shows that everything can be implemented using only tail recursion (which is essentially a WHILE loop). So iteration and recursion are equivalent.

Comment: Many IFs and a single WHILE.